# Relationship between threads, app domains and worker processes

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, iis, iis-7

In IIS7 and ASP.NET, what is the exact relationship among:

- IIS Worker Processes
- Threads
- AppDomains
- Applications, and
- incoming requests.

I'm hoping for an answer in a format similar to :

"Each IIS worker process hosts many appdomains which each spawn a single thread in response to each request...." etc. , and any nuances mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Each worker process hosts several AppDomains (at least one per ASP.NET app, i.e. a Website or Virtual Directory). An incoming request is assigned a thread from thread pool when it comes.

> OP: **Q.** So each appdomain owns and manages its own thread pool?

Each managed Thread is always assigned to a single AppDomain at a time. The worker process maintains a shared thread pool and it's assigned to a specific AppDomain for the duration of a request.

Answer (score 1):

Fritz Onion's book Essential ASP.NET has a [chapter on HTTP Pipeline](http://books.google.com/books?id=EeqGCtdsjOUC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=fritz+onion+appdomain+iis&source=bl&ots=281erIRxg-&sig=QP7_tHWWwteo5VwWq0AusHxDUFY&hl=en&ei=iNAOStnmHs6fmAfD6MX0Bw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1#PPA98,M1) where he talks about relationship of all of the above during http request.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to be for IIS5, and also doesn't mention threads as far as I can see.